# How to populate QQueue with list of signals?

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals, qt5

I wish to create something like this

**QQueue<*SIGNAL>* m_queue;**

So I can enqueue signals( n numbers ), and deque the same and process( means emit signals ).

Can anyone have any idea, whether is this possible or not ?

**Note:**
Motivation to this design is, I canot use UI thread for heavy processing, so i will create worker thread and worker thread will dequeue, the signals and process the same.

Comment: Can't you store `std::function`s, thus fill it with `lambda`s that capture the objects on which to invoke the `signal`s? Or even pointers to member functions, but the first solution seems to me more C++11/14/...

Comment: I cannot use std::function s, in our project. I would like to know is qt having any updates.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a worker object residing in a `QThread` and connect the desired signals using `Qt::QueuedConnection`. An emit will then just queue the signal for processing into the worker threads event queue.

As soon as the worker thread enters its event loop (worker object currently not processing anything), the signals will be processed ("dequeued").

No need to reinvent the wheel.